# Don't understand Thread o/p

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm doing scjp study,
My question is as below:

```
public class Bunnies extends Thread{


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thread t = new Thread(new Bunnies());
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new Bunnies());
        t.start();
        t1.start();

    }
    public  void run()
    {
        for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+"  ");
        }
    }

}
```

When I run above program, i get the o/p as below:

```
Thread-1  
Thread-1  
Thread-1  
Thread-3  
Thread-3  
Thread-3
```

Here I don't understand why Thread-2 is not displaying here, only Thread 1&3.

Please Explain.

Comment: Thanks to all of u .... now I understood the logic here:)

Answer (score 4):

Each time you create a `Bunnies`, which extends `Thread`, you also create a `Thread` hence the gaps in the numbers.

Your first run: `Thread t = new Thread(new Bunnies());`. `new Bunnies()` is `Thread-0` and `t` is `Thread-1`.
Then you run `Thread t1 = new Thread(new Bunnies());`.  `new Bunnies()` is `Thread-2` and `t1` is `Thread-3`.

Note however that you should not rely on thread numbering as [the javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#Thread%28%29) does not guarantee that the numbers will be consecutive.

You can verify with this code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Bunnies b = new Bunnies();
    Thread t = new Thread(b);
    Bunnies b1 = new Bunnies();
    Thread t1 = new Thread(b1);
    System.out.println(b.getName()); //Thread-0
    System.out.println(t.getName()); //Thread-1
    System.out.println(b1.getName()); //Thread-2
    System.out.println(t1.getName()); //Thread-3
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Here I don't understand why Thread-2 is not displaying here; only Thread 1&3.

On an abstract view there are at minimum 5 threads: `main`, `t` and `t1`. (and two anonymous threads)

```
class Bunnies extends Thread
```

So, when you create an object of class `Bunnies`, a thread is created and JVM assignes it a name.

Since `main` doesn't execute `run` method and anonymous threads are not started, i.e. `start()` is not called. Only `t` and `t1` will execute `run` method and hence you are getting only two thread names.

The sequence of naming will be as follows:

[image]

Comment: How can a thread be running if it wasn't started? `new Thread()` **doesn't create a thread**, any more than `new File()` creates a file.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: Agreed. rephrased.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have two `Bunnies` threads. It's up to the runtime how to it chooses to name them. In your case it chooses to call them `Thread-1` and `Thread-3`. Presumably, this happens because you subclass `Thread` and not `Runnable`. As a result you end up with four thread objects, of which only two are run as separate threads.

If you want them to be called something else, you can use the [`Thread.setName()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setName%28java.lang.String%29) method.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not specify a thread name explicitly, one is generated by the Runtime environment.

It is up to the runtime to generate these thread names. Probably the name "Thread-2" was already in use, e.g. for some background thread, so the next available one would have been "Thread-3".

As @assylias properly recognized, the reason that `Thread-2` is already in use is that `Bunnies` itself is a Thread, so when creating the Thread `t`, not only one but two threads are already created for which the runtime creates unique names.

Answer (score 0):

In your code,Bunnies is a Thread(and a Runnable),but you use it as it's only a Runnable, actually you should do it like this:

```
public class Bunnies extends Thread {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thread t = new Bunnies();
        Thread t1 = new Bunnies();
        t.start();
        t1.start();

    }

    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + "  ");
        }
    }
}
```

or like this:

```
public class Bunnies implements Runnable{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thread t = new Thread(new Bunnies());
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new Bunnies());
        t.start();
        t1.start();

    }

    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + "  ");
        }
    }
}
```